# Php Copy database to a duplicate using cpanel xaml API or something similar

Tags: php, cpanel, database-backups

I have two databases for my website. One I run my live website and the other I run a development website. My need is to copy the live database to dev database everyday.

Is there some xml API to achieve this, which will copy my database to another whichever name I want and then rename it further according to my needs.

I have to achieve this entirely using php (No Phpmyadmin interface).

I tried BigDump.php but since my database size is more than 100MB the script breaks.

Comment: You may use `mysqldump` command in command line: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html At the end you get an .sql file with the create and insert statements. You can compress it, download to your local system and import it to another db with the `mysql` command from command line. It is possible to do all of this via cronjob.

Comment: @steven forgot to mention that. My client wants a button which when clicked will run a php file. This php file will generate the dump and place it somewhere on server and then again import that to development database using the dump.

Comment: you can execute command line commands from php via `exec` or something similar. If you have already a script which do that (like you wrote) you should increase the `max_execution_time` in php.ini to make your script be able to finish the work

Answer (score 0):

For this task, I will suggest you please setup cron through cPanel and use mysqldump command for the backup and restart that with mysql command.

You can create simple bash script for this task and setup that script in cron with everyday setting